# Drop observations with certain conditions iterating in the whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am sure this question have been already made several times, but for some reason I am not able to find the answer. Basically, I have a dataframe with 500 variables (columns) and 15000 observarions (rows). The values of the variables ranges from -140 to 100, in all the obsertations.

[image]

Basically, I need to remove the observations (rows) that have some values that are between -20 and 0.

I tried with (X_train are the 500 variables):

```
for i in X_train.columns:
    a=X_train[(X_train[i] >= -20) & (X_train[i] <= 0) ]
```

And also with this:

```
a = X_train[(X_train.iloc[:,:].values > -20) & (X_train.iloc[:,:].values < -0)]
```

The first code gives me a dataframe full of NA's, and the second one a dataframe with 0 rows.

Someone could help me with the correct syntaxis for this?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
for col in X_train.columns:
    mask = list(X_train[col] <= 0) & (X_train[col] >= -20)
    X_train = X_train.loc[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work ( i.e. remove rows which have any values between -20 and 0 ) :

```
 df[(df<-20)|(df>0)].dropna()
```